# How to optimize suspend time with XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8, microsoft-metro, xmlserializer

I want to submit a newsapp to the Windows Store, but it always fails the App Certification process (local check before submission), because I serialize the data to an XML file with the XmlSerializer when the app is suspended (OnSuspended-Event). When I don't serialize, the app successfully passes this Certification process...

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994640.aspx) suggests the following:

> When you do serialize your data, you should avoid reserializing if it
>   hasn't changed. It takes extra time to serialize and save the data,
>   plus extra time to read and deserialize it when the app is activated
>   again. Instead, we recommend that **the app determine if its state has
>   actually changed, and if so, serialize and deserialize only the data
>   that changed**.

I really like this idea, but unfortunately don't know how to achieve it. I have a collection with news-items (downloaded on app start) and the user downloads details for those news-items. So, basically at suspension I only should serialize those details and can serialize the news-items after the initial load. How can I achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess the OS detects that the file you write has the exact same contents as before. You could work around that by serializing a `Guid.NewGuid()` every time.

Comment: @usr. thank you very much for your valuable comment. That's a great point: I now added a global variable which I check if something has changed. With this, I could finally pass the Certification Requirements Process. - Does someone have any idea of how to serialize only changed items and not everything? - Thanks.

Comment: such a feature is not built-in. It is a lot of work to implement that. If you only serialize a few KB I really wouldn't bother with it (because it makes no difference) and just add a random value to cheat-pass the requirements.

Comment: @usr: so if it is about 400 KB and can easily grow to 1 MB? - The serialization really goes fast anyway, but I don't want any troubles on this part of the app... At the moment, I only serialize if something changed. Otherwise it makes no sense for me to serialize anything, because I already did that... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple read-only data:

1. On App Load if cache file exists deserialize it into memory object.
2. On User Request, fetch update from service, merge results and serialize everything immediately.
3. On Suspend, nothing to do. Your data is already persisted after update occurred.

What if the user makes some changes:

1. On App Load if cache file exists deserialize it into memory object.
2. On User Edit, update to/from service, merge results and serialize everything immediately.
3. On Suspend, nothing to do. Your data is already persisted after update occurred.

The real takeaway here is that you should have nothing or almost nothing to do at time of suspend. The suspend event is intended to give your app time to save its state. It is not intended to save its data. This is because the slightest hiccup can cause your save process to fail, and because you only have a few seconds (with NO mercy) your data is lost and your app looks bad.

Because of fast app switching, the cache you already have in memory will not change. Because you explicitly monitor for updates from the service or changes by the user, there is no reason for you to "determine" if there are deltas between what is in memory and what is in the cache file.

Another suggestion, do not serialize the whole object into a single file if it is huge. There is no reason you cannot break your classes and lists up and serialize them separately for performance reasons. To be honest, this is very common.

Comment: wonderful explanation. that's exactly what I am going to do! Thank you!